# Can I have a DNS MX record for outgoing and a different MX record for incoming?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

I'm configuring an email service for my domain. I plan on using Zoho Mail for free because I can use a business domain professional email. I want to use Zoho Mail to send out messages, but I have email forwards in my GoDaddy mail settings that I want to still use to collect incoming email, instead of it going to Zoho Mail.

If I keep the MX record in my DNS for the GoDaddy email forwards and add the Zoho MX record in my DNS, but give it a lower priority will that effectively send all incoming mail through the GoDaddy MX record and Zoho Mail will be sent out using the Zoho MX record?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is suitable for this Q&A site or it would be better posted to the Webmasters Exchange instead.

Comment: MX records have no bearing on your outbound email. MX records designate where email is delivered for your domain, not where it originates from.

Comment: @joeqwerty So I could remove the MX record for the Zoho Mail and I would still be able to send mail out, but then the incoming mail would be handled using the MX record?

Comment: I have no idea what service Zoho offers or how you're using it, but if you don't want your email being delivered to Zoho then you should not have an MX record designating Zoho for your domain.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information @joeqwerty. Feel really stupid now and this question will probably just a ton of downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MX records are used to designate servers that will receive email for a domain.

If you want to have a server send email for a domain, then you should set up SPF, DKIM, and reverse lookup records for the host that will send email.